# Fourier Transform of Dielectric Function in 2D

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, fourier-transform

According to "Dielectric screening in two-dimensional insulators: Implications for excitonic and impurity states in graphane", https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.085406, the Fourier transform of the dielectric function in 2D is not a constant as in 3D.

I was trying to get this result by a different way than the paper and got a constant, which I expect is the 3D result. Can you tell me where I went wrong, please?

I started by writing that the total potential in a material relates to the potential of the charges external to the polarization (with this I mean the part of the electric field that is not generated by the polarized charges) by

$$ \phi_{ext}(\textbf{r},t) = \int d^3\textbf{r}' dt' \epsilon (\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}',t - t') \phi_{tot}(\textbf{r}',t') $$

where $ \epsilon (\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}',t - t') $ is the dielectric function.

Computing the Fourier transform of the last equation we get

$$ \phi_{ext}(\textbf{q},\omega) = \epsilon(\textbf{q},\omega) \phi_{tot}(\textbf{q},\omega) $$

and since $ \phi_{tot}(\textbf{q},\omega) = \phi_{ext}(\textbf{q},\omega) + \phi_{ind}(\textbf{q},\omega) $, where $ \phi_{ind}(\textbf{q},\omega) $ is the potential due to the charges induced by the polarization, we have

$$ \epsilon^{-1}(\textbf{q},\omega) = 1 + \frac{\phi_{ind}(\textbf{q},\omega)}{\phi_{ext}(\textbf{q},\omega)}. $$

Then I used the relations

$$ P(\textbf{r},t) = - \chi_e \nabla \phi_{tot}(\textbf{r},t), \ \ \ \ -\nabla^2 \phi_{ind}(\textbf{r},t) = n_{ind}(\textbf{r},t) = - \nabla P(\textbf{r},t) $$

which implies that

$$ \phi_{ind}(\textbf{q},\omega) = - \chi_e \epsilon^{-1}(\textbf{q},\omega) \phi_{ext}(\textbf{q},\omega). $$

Computing this with the result for the inverse of the dielectric function yields

$$ \epsilon(\textbf{q},\omega) = 1 + \chi_e. $$

If I didn't make any mistake, I expect this is the right result for 3D. However, I don't understand where impose it to be 3D and not 2D. Where did I restrict the dimension?

Comment: Do you think it might be because the polarization, due to the constraints of the lattice, has one less dimension than the external field and the actual field?